# Line of maximum density in liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

Why is the thermal expansion coefficient zero along the line of maximum density in liquids? Why is $(∂^{2}V/∂T^{2})_{P} > 0$ along the same line?

Comment: 'Cause it's maximum - that's how extrema are found analytically! I don't think it's a place for basic questions about derivatives.